# Angular form group to filter rows in Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, typescript

Pretty new in Angular,
How to render FormGroup in Angular Material table?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-grid-view',
  templateUrl: './grid-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grid-view.component.scss']
})
export class GridViewComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() dataSource!: IndexDataSource;
  @Input() sortField: string = 'id'
  @Input() sortOrder: SortDirection = 'desc';
  @Input() tableColumns: Array<IColumn> = [];
  @Input() model = '';

  // Handle pagination property
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator!: MatPaginator;

  // Handle sorting property
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort!: MatSort;

  // Handle column that will be displayed
  displayedColumns: Array<string> = [];

  // For handle row search by each column
  displayedColumnsSearch: Array<string> = [];
  fieldsOfFormSearch: Array<any> = [];

  // For filters, accommodate the filter inputs
  filterValues: { [key: string]: string } = {};
  filterString!: string;

  // FormGroup to hold filter form controls
  formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  @Output() filterChange = new EventEmitter<{ [key: string]: string }>();

  ngOnInit(): void {

    // => Init rows based on param url
    let paramMap = this.dataSource.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap;
    this.dataSource.loadData(
      Number(paramMap.get('page')) || 1,
      Number(paramMap.get('per-page')) || 10,
      paramMap.get('sort') || this.sortField,
      paramMap.get('sort')?.startsWith("-") ? 'asc' : this.sortOrder,
      paramMap.get('filter') || this.filterString
    );

    //  => Column that will display in table
    this.displayedColumns = this.tableColumns.map((column) => column.columnDef);

    // => Form element that will be displayed in second row
    this.fieldsOfFormSearch = this.tableColumns.map((column) => ({
      status: column.isFilterable !== undefined,
      formControl: column.columnDef + 'Search',
      urlSearch: this.model + `[${column.columnDef}]`,
    }));

    // => Create form controls for filter inputs and add them to the FormGroup
    this.fieldsOfFormSearch
      .filter((field) => field.status)
      .forEach((field) => {

        let formControl = new FormControl();
        this.formGroup.addControl(field.urlSearch, formControl);

        formControl.valueChanges
          .pipe(debounceTime(300), distinctUntilChanged())
          .subscribe((value: any) => {
            this.filterValues[field.urlSearch] = value;
            this.applyFilters();
          });
      });

    // Column that will be display in table
    this.displayedColumnsSearch = this.fieldsOfFormSearch.map((c) => c.urlSearch);

    // Debug the form control
    console.log(this.formGroup);

  }

  applyFilters() {
    this.filterString = Object.keys(this.filterValues)
      .map((key) => `${key}=${this.filterValues[key]}`)
      .join('&');
    this.dataSource.applyFilters(this.filterString);
    this.filterChange.emit(this.filterValues);
  }

}

The in `grid-view.component.html`
```

```
<!-- Actual Data -->
<ng-container *ngFor="let column of tableColumns;"
              matColumnDef="{{column.columnDef}}">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{column.header}}</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{column.cell(element)}}</td>
</ng-container>

<!--  Filter Data  -->
<ng-container *ngFor="let field of fieldsOfFormSearch"
              matColumnDef="{{field.urlSearch}}"
>
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
    <span *ngIf="!field.status; else displayField"></span>
    <ng-template #displayField>
      <!--          Filtering here-->
      A form control here how to render it ?
      
    </ng-template>
  </th>
</ng-container>


<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsSearch"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
```

```

UPDATE,

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let field of fieldsOfFormSearch"
                  matColumnDef="{{field.urlSearch}}"
    >
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <span *ngIf="!field.status; else displayField"></span>
        <ng-template #displayField>
          <!--          Filtering here-->
          <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <input
              matInput
              [formControl]="field.formControl"
              (input)="applyFilters()"
            >
          </mat-form-field>
        </ng-template>
      </th>
    </ng-container>
```

ERROR:

```
ERROR TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function
ERROR TypeError: this.ngControl.control.hasValidator is not a function
```

Comment: It's not different than rendering a regular form control. Docs [here](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field).

Comment: No Idea, how to render it correctly. Please see my update

Comment: Did you follow the trace of the errors? The call stack should give you a good hint on that.

Answer (score 0):

Yours "field.formControl" are "strings", so you can enclosed the table in a `<form [formGroup]="formGroup">` and use `[formControlName]="field.formControl"` instead of "[formControl]"

Another option is create the formGroup **before**, and in map use

```
this.fieldsOfFormSearch = this.tableColumns.map((column) => ({
      status: column.isFilterable !== undefined,
      //see that you equal the formControl property to a FormControl, 
      //not to a string
      formControl: this.formGroup.get(column.columnDef + 'Search') as FormControl,
      urlSearch: this.model + `[${column.columnDef}]`,
    }));
```